# How to draw the graph of $x^6 = y^3$ and $3y = (\log x)^2$?

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

For example, if the equation is $x^4 = y^2$ then I can separate this to get the two equations $y = x^2$ and $y = - x^2$ , hence I can plot the two graphs. But how do I simplify the given equation?

I have understood how to draw the graph if the first equation, could you please help me with the second graph?

Comment: When you solve for y there is only one graph, since cubic roots are unique in the reals.  So the equation just reduces to $y=x^2$.

Comment: @Paul This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Paul Could you please help me with the graph of 3y = (log x)^2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunate you, there will arise only one case while solving $y^6=x^3$, since you're having cube over $x$, hence the expression will simply reduce to

> $y^2=x$

[image]

Comment: $y^2=x$ is rotated parabola

Comment: thanks i got this part. But how do I graph the other equation? I know how to graph log x but i am not able to graph this function composition.

Comment: @rlartiga Silly me. I had rectified that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$3y = (logx)^2$ divided by 3 is $y = (1/3)*((log x)^2)$

Assuming you know how to plot the graph of $log x$ the graph of $(log x)^2$

Should look something like this!

Because by squaring the negative values they become positive and the rest of the graph just becomes a little taller than the one for $log x$

[image: Should look something like this.]

Now to get the graph you requested you simply divide all y values by 3 and plot this exact graph making it a little shorter HaHa!

Here's what it should look like!

[image: Here's what it should look like!]

Hope that's the answer of your question!